# Not able to set filter in a "Rally.data.wsapi.artifact.Store"

Tags: filter, rally

I am using a `rallymilestonecombobox` to display milestones.
I am selecting the milestone and getting the correct value when I output to `console.log`.

When I select the new milestone I update the filter.
The filter isn't loading or updating in the store.

Initially I tried `filters: myFilters` but that didn't work in the artifact.Store.

It worked when I used

```
"filters:
  [{
    property : 'Milestones',
    operator : 'contains',
    value : myFilters.value
  }],"
```

But I am not successful in updating the filter on the update ".load".

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    myStore: undefined,
    storyGrid: undefined,
    storyStore: undefined,

    // Intital Layout
    width: 1600,
    height: 1200,
    items: [{
            xtype: 'container',
            itemId: 'pulldown-container',
            padding: '25,5,5,25',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            itemId: 'group-container',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
            },

            items: [{
                    title: 'Stories',
                    xtype: 'container',
                    itemId: 'story-grid-container',
                    padding: '20,5,5,25',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'vbox',
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'Story info',
                    xtype: 'tabpanel',
                    itemId: 'story-info-container',
                    padding: '5,5,5,25', //top, right, bottom, left).
                    autoScroll: true,
                    layout: {
                        type: 'vbox',
                    },
                }
            ]
        }
    ],

    launch: function() {
        // Load Releases in ComboBox
        // this._loadReleases();
        this._loadMilestones();
    },

    _loadMilestones: function() {
        // Create Milestone ComboBox
        var milestoneComboBox = {
            xtype: 'rallymilestonecombobox',
            itemId: 'milestone-combo-box',
            fieldLabel: 'Milestones',
            labelAlign: 'right',
            width: 300,
            listeners: {
                ready: this._loadData,
                select: this._loadData,
                scope: this
            }
        };

        this.down('#pulldown-container').add(milestoneComboBox);
    },

    //construct filters for given milestone
    _getMilestoneFilters: function(milestoneValue) {
        var milestoneFilter = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Filter', {
            property: 'Milestone',
            operation: '=',
            value: milestoneValue
        });

        return milestoneFilter;
    },

    //Get data from rally
    _loadData: function() {
        var selectedMilestoneRef = this.down('#milestone-combo-box').getRecord().get('_ref');
        var myFilters = this._getMilestoneFilters(selectedMilestoneRef);

        console.log(myFilters);

        //if store exists, load new data
        if (this.myStore) {
            this.myStore.setFilter(myFilters);
            this.myStore.load();
        } else {
            //create store
            this.myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.artifact.Store', {
                models: ['User Story', 'Defect'],
                autoLoad: true,
                filters: [{
                    property: 'Milestones',
                    operator: 'contains',
                    value: myFilters.value
                }],
                listeners: {
                    load: function() {
                        this._onStoriesForMilestoneLoad();
                    },
                    scope: this
                },
                fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name']
            });
        }
    },

    _onStoriesForMilestoneLoad: function() {
        if (!this.down('#my-grid')) {
            var gridListeners = {
                itemclick: {
                    fn: function(record, item) {
                        this._createStoryInfo(record, item);
                        this._createRevisionInfo(record, item);
                    }
                },
                scope: this
            };

            var columnCfgs = ['FormattedID', 'Name'];
            this._createGrid('my-grid', this.myStore, gridListeners, '#story-grid-container', columnCfgs, 600, 775, null);
        }
    },

    _createGrid: function(id, theStore, theListeners, container, theColumnCfgs, gridwidth, gridheight, tabTitle) {
        var storyGrid = {
            title: tabTitle,
            xtype: 'rallygrid',
            itemId: id,
            store: theStore,
            listeners: theListeners,
            context: this.getContext(),
            columnCfgs: theColumnCfgs,
            enableEditing: false,
            showRowActionsColumn: false,
            enableScheduleStateClickable: false,
            verticalScroller: false,
            showPagingToolbar: false,
            width: gridwidth,
            height: gridheight,
            forceFit: true,
        };

        this.down(container).add(storyGrid);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update the Filter value specifically and it worked.
I should have known since I had to do this when creating the store.

```
     //if store exists, load new data
     if(this.myStore)
     {
        this.myStore.clearFilter(true);           
        this.myStore.filter([
        {
                property : 'Milestones',
                operator : 'contains',
                value : myFilters.value
        }]);

       this.myStore.load();
     }
     else
     {
        //create store
        this.myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.artifact.Store',
        {
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out this example:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/example/filterable-grid

It's a little different than your use case, but the mechanics are still the same.
The important bit is this:

```
var myFilters = this._getMilestoneFilters(selectedMilestoneRef);
if (this.myStore) {
      this.myStore.clearFilter(true);
      this.myStore.filter([myFilters]); //notice, it's an array
}
```

There's also an app baseclass to make it easy to work with timebox scoping since it is such a common use case:

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/timebox_filtering

You could extend Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp, set scopeType to milestone and go from there.  It will handle creating the milestone combo for you.  And it will also automatically support working on milestone scoped custom pages in Rally.

I think you're probably really close to working code in your existing implementation, but worth a consideration to look into TimeboxScopedApp...

Comment: It doesn't seem to be updating the grid. The store seems to update when I output it to console.

Comment: I updated the code example.  the call to myStore.filter takes an array, which I did not have before.  Seems to work for me.  Give it a try!